# Get column name dynamically in AspxGridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am working with Aspxgridview with contrxtmenustrip in web application.
In aspxgridview there are 5 columns with some row data. Post right click on grid I need to know which row user has clicked and what is the column name without passing the column index manually in code level.

```
int rowVisibleIndex = int.Parse(hf["VisibleIndex"].ToString());
```

By doing this I am able to get the row number. In the same way I need the column name which is selected by user at client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.Rows['Index of selected row']['Index or column name of cell you want to get value` from']
```

that in concrete:

```
gridView.Rows[gridView.SelectedRowIndex]["ID"]
```

**UPDATE** and for column Header use this :

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    string headerText = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But i required the column name at run time which user selected from aspxgridview.

Comment: On cell click we need header of selected cell column. The above event which was given is not found in devexpress aspxgridview control.

Comment: I am looking answer for ASPXGridview (devexpress) control not for Microsoft grid control.